# Binding a NSComboBox to an NSArrayController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I can't populate a `NSComboBox`. I'm trying to bind it programmatically to an `NSArrayController`:

```
frequencyArrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] initWithContent:nil];
[frequencyArrayController setManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp mainWindowDocument] managedObjectContext]];
[frequencyArrayController setEntityName:@"Frequency"];
[frequencyArrayController fetch:self];
[frequencyComboBox bind:@"contentValues" toObject:frequencyArrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.DisplayName" options:nil];
```

What am I missing?

The field is on a `NSPanel` which is not open yet when the app starts. I'm binding it and loading the nib in advance, is this an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your array controller to fetch: at some point.

Edit: Here's the example code I'm using to test:

```
    arrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
    [arrayController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [arrayController setEntityName:@"Entity"];
    [comboBox bind:@"contentValues" toObject:arrayController         
        withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name" options:nil];
    [arrayController fetch:self];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
       NSLog(@"%@", comboBox.objectValues); 
    }];
```

Check that your MOC and IBOutlets are non-nil.

Comment: I've tried this with no results: [frequencyArrayController fetch:self];

Comment: Have you verified that the array controller is actually populated after the fetch command? (Note: objects are not fetched immediately, you'll have to test on the next run loop) It's working in my test app.